# How to make HorizontalListView inside Listview with dynamic height in flutter?

Tags: flutter-layout

I am developing a Flutter application and I want to dynamically adjust the height of the ListView inside other ListView.

I would like to make ListView & inside dynamic height Horizontal Listview.

Can any one help me.?

Comment: did you try anything? can you post your code?

Comment: Yes. My code is same like below answer but I don't  want to sst horizontal list height fixed. If I set it fixed size of container it's but in my case it's dynamic so any other solution do you have?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `ListViewBuilder` inside a `Container` and it is a child of `Column`.

You can set the height for the container and it works.

```
SingleChildScrollView(
 child :Column( 
    children :[
         Container:
              child: ListView.builder(
                              scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                               itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                                             return Text('$index'),
                               },
                               itemCount = 10 ,
                      ),
              height : 100.0 ,
    ]
 ),
  scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
)
```

Comment: Yes. If I set height it's work but my horizontal listview height not fixed that's main problem.

Comment: you're right , you can use LimitedBox or SizedBox widget instead of container . plz test them too.

Comment: Yes. I try LimitedBox in that we need to specify maxHeight I am set my screen max height and minHeight as 10 but it's always make view same height as maxHeight. And in SizedBox we need to pass height still I am stopped at height parameter.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, I might have a solution for you.
You could wrap your widgets in a **[LayoutBuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/LayoutBuilder-class.html)** like so:

```
LayoutBuilder(
  builder: (context, constraints) {
    return SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            child: ListView.builder(
              scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
              itemCount: 10,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return Text('$index');
              },
            ),
            height: constraints.maxHeight * kConstant,
          ),
        ],
      ),
      scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
    );
  },
);
```

kConstant is a double value between 1 and 0 that scales your height.
That way the heigth is no more absolute but dynamic. The contraints are provided by the parent widget, so constraints.maxHeight will give you the maximum height of the widget the lies before LayoutBuilder in the widget tree.

Hope this helps.